# SortableJS multi drag not working when using appendChild

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I have two lists of elements that get dynamically created, question groups (left) and questions (right). I want to be able to drag multiple questions from a list on the right onto a question group on the left and have those questions get appended to the appropriate question list. When I step through the code the questions seem to be getting appended but I believe that SortableJS is somehow erroring or cancelling the append.

The issue may be with mixing plain JS and SortableJS. This plain JS event has the appendChild code I wish to attain:

```
    document.addEventListener("drop", function (event, target) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //Element being moved.
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text/html");

        if (event.target.classList.contains("question-group-item") && !$(data).get(0).classList.contains("question-group-item")) {
            //Blink group item being dropped into.
            $(event.target).effect("highlight", { color: "#0093d2" }, 3000);

            //Get group being dropped to.
            var groupID = $(event.target).attr('data-group-id');

            //Get all items being dropped.
           sortableArray.forEach(function (questionElem) {
                $(questionElem).attr('data-group-id', groupID);
                document.getElementById("list-tab-" + groupID).appendChild(questionElem);
            });

            //Set new group ID.
            //document.getElementById($(data).attr('id')).setAttribute('data-group-id', groupID);
            //document.getElementById("list-tab-" + groupID).appendChild(document.getElementById($(data).attr('id')));
        }

        updateObjects();
    });
```

Here is a JS Bin:

https://jsbin.com/xakajusedu/edit?js,output

Comment: @Owen M do you have any insight?

Comment: Use the `onEnd` event in each of the Sortable's you want the drop action to be called for, and it will be fired after multiDrag has completed adding the elements so it won't add them after you have moved their position

Comment: @Owen M I accomplished what I needed to get done by treating each list item in the left list (question group) as if it were itself a sortable list. The issue with your comment above is that I needed to get the element of the list item I'm dropping onto, not the list itself. I updated the JS Bin, is there a cleaner way of doing this?